# Setting system property org.gradle.java.home doens't help to start Gradle build

Tags: gradle

I have a system which doesn't have the `java` binary in `PATH`, neither does it have `JAVA_HOME` set - this is on purpose for testing. I'm trying to invoke a Gradle build, and for that, I'm specifying `org.gradle.java.home`:

```
./gradlew -Dorg.gradle.java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

but it fails:

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the location of your Java installation.
```

Accordong to the Gradle 2.14.1 docs found here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html

```
org.gradle.java.home
Specifies the Java home for the Gradle build process. The value can be set to either a jdk or jre location, however, depending on what your build does, jdk is safer. A reasonable default is used if the setting is unspecified.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Java home for the Gradle **build** process

`org.gradle.java.home` is used during build process but gradle itself (either standalone distribution or wrapper) uses JDK from `JAVA_HOME` environment variable or (if it is not set) from `PATH`.

Gradle wrapper is a jar file + simple shell startup script, it requires working `java` binary to run.

You can use something like this:
`JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64 ./gradlew`

Inline environment variable works in bash, not sure about other shells.

Comment: this answer is so useful, for not only explaining why setting via -D doesn't work, but for also giving a working answer.